# How does an inverter use excess solar capacity to charge a DC connected battery?

Tags: solar-panels, inverter

Given the following home solar setup:

- 10KW of solar panels
- 5KW (Fronius Gen24) inverter
- 10KWH DC attached battery

And it is a sunny day with the potential of generating a full 10WK from the solar panels.
And the battery is at 5% charge. 
And the house is currently consuming 3KW

**Assuming the system is configured correctly, what should happen (and why)?**

1. The excess solar capacity is used to charge the DC battery:

```
  Then 3KW is consumed by the house
  And 7KW is used to charge the battery
```

2. DC charging is limited to the inverter AC capacity limit by [clipping](https://www.solarquotes.com.au/blog/inverter-clipping-throttling-mb2718/):

```
  Then 3KW is consumed by the house
  And 2KW is used to charge the battery
```

3. DC charging is limited to the [max PV power of the inverter](https://www.fronius.com/en-au/australia/solar-energy/installers-partners/technical-data/all-products/inverters/fronius-primo-gen24/fronius-primo-gen24-5-0):

```
  Then 3KW is consumed by the house
  And 4.5KW is used to charge the battery
```

4. Something else: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

References:

- [Fronius Gen24 Tech Data](https://www.fronius.com/en-au/australia/solar-energy/installers-partners/technical-data/all-products/inverters/fronius-primo-gen24/fronius-primo-gen24-5-0)

Comment: you answered your own question, yes it can

Comment: @jsotola I gave three different possibilities (4 if you include 'something else') - which one is the most accurate?

Comment: I'm presuming the battery (and charge controller) is on the solar panel side of the inverter? Or are you running ac from the inverter to a battery charger?

Comment: Note that this depends on your equipment. Mine has synchronized inverters at the panels; the power is AC before it gets to the rest of the house, so yes, I would then have to convert it to DC before charging the battery and then convert the battery output back to AC to use it, with some loss of efficiency. Your setup may be different.

Comment: @JonCuster The battery is attached via DC to the (Fronius) inverter.  So I'd say it's on the solar panel side of the inverter based on my understanding, but I'm not an electrician.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of it as a 7.5 kW solar charge controller to a battery.... Plus a separate 5kW inverter... same as if you bought those components as separates.  They are in a single enclosure and acting on the same battery.

So your solar production will be capped at 7.5 kW because that's all the charge controller you paid for.
Your AC output will be capped at 5kW because that's the size of your AC inverter.

In your scenario, your battery will charge at 7.5 kW and then simultaneously discharge at 3 kW, leaving 4.5 kW net charge. So 3) is the closest.